# iPhone : How to manage 130 images in ImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have more then 100 images which I use to load in imageView using following code :

```
   [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png",prefixName,counter]]];
```

where above code will be called each 0.03s and `counter` is number for loading different images.

Above idea gives me animation effect, where it use to load different image on 0.03s.

But when the images are more it use to `crash`.

What should I do ? Or How do I maintain memory in my case? any idea?

Comment: Try pre-creating the images, not loading and setting them in one line, as you have done.  It's possible to show many minutes of video, synchronized with sound, by setting up a dispatch queue to load and cache the images.

Comment: please copy&paste the crash log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:extension];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];
[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

instead of

```
[imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName.extension]];
```

Also UIImageView have setAnimationImages method

```
imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
[imgView setAnimationImages:myArray];//myArray - array of Images
[imgView setAnimationDuration:1];
[imgView setAnimationRepeatCount=0];
[imgView startAnimating];
[self addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: +1 for setAnimationImages, but storing 100 images in-memory might lead to large memory footprints and crash, so that one is most probably not correct

Comment: For all we know the images might only be 10kb in size each and no memory issue.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are doing this:

```
[imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png",prefixName,counter]]];
```

in a loop. Each of the `imageNamed:` objects is getting allocated, but released only when the autorelease pool gets drained. Try to use this code instead:

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",prefixName,counter] ofType:@"png"]];
imgV.image = img;
[img release];
```